# black screen on dual boot - but not always (Win 7 / Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I know this is a common problem but even after like four days of reading through different forums I wasn't able to fix it. I'm fairly new to Linux, by the way, so sorry in advance.
Here's the situation:

I have an old Toshiba Satellite C660 with Windows 7. A week ago I installed Ubuntu 16.04 as the second OS, using the method of creating a new partition by shrinking an existing one. Even though Ubuntu installed just fine, ever since that time when I start the laptop I have about 50% chance of just getting a black screen. No BIOS splash screen, no recovery mode, nothing. I have to do a hard reboot and then it starts normally, BIOS splash screen, then grub loader etc. The weird thing is, it really only happens in about 50% of cases and at other times it boots normally. Even though I can always start the system eventually by doing the hard reboot, it's very annoying.

What I tried so far:
Boot-Repair on recommended mode
Updating / reinstalling the grub
Editing the grub file in different ways (quiet splash, nomode set, etc.)

I don't know if it's related but my brightness keys don't work either.

I use integrated graphics: Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset.

The output of `sudo lshw -c display`:

```
*-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f2800000-f2bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f2100000-f21fffff
```

Thank you guys in advance for any help. Apart from this issue I'm having a blast using Ubuntu and learning all this new stuff, it's really awesome.

Comment: Will you add the output of `sudo lshw -c display` to your question?

Comment: sorry if it's a duplicate; I read through the thread you mentioned multiple times and tried the suggestion that applied to my case, unfortunately the problem still persists

Comment: If you're not even getting a BIOS POST screen it sounds like it's unrelated to Ubuntu and related to BIOS.

Comment: but it only started happening after I created the dual-boot. Before, I always single-booted straight into windows without any problems. It might be a graphics card issue because the screen brightness control stopped working as well.